# Manipulating data in a Microsoft Access table

Tags: ms-access, macros, datatable

I have a large database of client details, and I need to generate a totally new field of data based on a single other field.  It would be a simple IF..THEN deal.

Example:
The source field has data that looks like this "BAR DIN" (Barrie Dinners) and I need to fill a new field with "Dinners".

From what I understand, Data Macros are the right way to do this, but I'd prefer not to buy Access 2010.  There should be a way to do this with normal macros.  This update only needs to be done once a year and can be done manually.  I mostly looking for a way to avoid having to enter all that data manually for each customer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate table to translate between the two:

```
source_field new_field
BAR DIN      Barrie Dinners
FOO BROS     Foo Brothers
```

Anytime you need to see the "new_field" values, JOIN that translation table to your original table (JOIN on source_field) to look them up.  This approach is one of the fundamental reasons **relational** databases were created in the first place.  This way your database will **always** be "up to date" without the need for any macros to populate a redundant field.